# Convert sed with multiple expressions to python

Tags: python, regex, replace, sed

I have the following sed script:

```
cat foo.txt | sed -e "s/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g" -e "s/ //g" -e "s/'//g"
```

Which can be translated into three expressions:

1. Captures all text between `[...]`
2. Removes white-spaces
3. Removes all single quotes

What's a neat way to do something similar with a text file in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it all with regular expressions (`re.sub()`) but this does it mostly with plain Python, just using regular expressions for the initial capture.

```
import re

s = "some string ['foo'] [b a r] [baz] [] extra stuff"

pat0 = re.compile(r'\[([^]]*)\]')

lst0 = pat0.findall(s)

lst1 = [s.replace(' ', '') for s in lst0]
lst2 = [s.replace("'", '') for s in lst1]

print(lst2) # prints: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()
    out_data = []
    for line in read_data:
        out_line = re.sub(r".*\[([^]]*)\].*", r"\1", line)
        out_line = re.sub(r" ", r"", out_line)
        out_line = re.sub(r"'", r"", out_line)
        out_data.append(out_line)
    # do whatever you want with out_data here
```

Comment: Python has a non-greedy repeat operator. The first regex looks more readable like: `r".*\[(.*?)\].*"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("\[([^\]]+)\]")

out = list()
for line in open("foo.txt", "rt"):
    out.extend(i.translate(None, "' ") for i in re.findall(regex, line.strip()))
print out
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the ugly one-liner, for those who like such things:

```
>>> [f for f in open("foo.txt", 'r')]
["some string ['foo'] [b a r] [baz] [] extra stuff\n"]
>>> [re.sub("[ ']", "", s) for s in re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", f) for f in open("foo.txt")]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', '']
```

Explaination, best explained with reading the code backwards:

1. Iterate through file, line by line. `open()` defaults to read-only.
2. `re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", f)` extracts contents of `[..]`.
3. And finally replace whitespace and `'` with nothing (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

```
s=r"dasdad [some where, dsadasd '''' sadads] hoda"
re.sub(r'[\'\s]*', '', re.sub(r'.*\[([^]]*)\].*', r'\1', s))
```

Output:

```
somewhere,dsadasdsadads
```